# "Home life happy?" meaning

Tags: meaning

in first part of the Poirot movie, there is a sentence:"Husband put head in gas oven. Home life happy?"

What does "Home life happy?" mean?

Comment: Note there is a question mark. It is shorthand for saying " If the husband just put his head in the gas oven, how could his home life have been happy?"

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps it was laughing gas.

Answer (score 2):

It means "Is his home life happy?"  By home life, they mean domestic life, living at home, being a family man, etc.